# How to get an unordered list to scroll with footer

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm a newbie to CSS and HTML. I just went through the [socket.io chat application tutorial](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) but found that when I typed too many messages to fit on the screen, I couldn't scroll down and see them. I've spent hours researching this, but can't find a solution. Everything seems to either have the scrollbar be for the entire page or have the input footer move off the bottom.

How can I get the unordered list to scroll so that the bottom message can be seen completely and the footer always stays at the bottom?

The current HTML is below:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Talk Page</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    form {
      background: #000;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    form input {
      border: 0;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 90%;
      margin-right: .5%;
    }
    form button {
      width: 9%;
      background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    content {
      width: 100%;
      bottom: 10%;
      display: block;
    }
    #messages {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #messages li {
      padding: 5px 10px;
    }
    #messages li:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #eee;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="overflow:hidden;">
  <div id="content" ; style="overflow:auto;">
    <ul id="messages" style="font: 13px Helvetica, Arial;">
      <li>test</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
      <li>13</li>
      <li>14</li>
      <li>15</li>
      <li>16</li>
      <li>17</li>
      <li>18</li>
      <li>19</li>
      <li>20</li>
      <li>21</li>
      <li>22</li>
      <li>23</li>
      <li>24</li>
      <li>25</li>
      <li>26</li>
      <li>27</li>
      <li>28</li>
      <li>29</li>
      <li>30</li>
      <li>31</li>
      <li>32</li>
      <li>33</li>
      <li>34</li>
      <li>35</li>
      <li>36</li>
      <li>37</li>
      <li>38</li>
      <li>39</li>
      <li>40</li>
      <li>41</li>
      <li>42</li>
      <li>43</li>
      <li>44</li>
      <li>45</li>
      <li>46</li>
      <li>47</li>
      <li>48</li>
      <li>49</li>
      <li>50</li>
      <li>last thing</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="footer" style="position:fixed; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px; overflow:hidden;">
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT:** After receiving a few answers, I realized I need to be a bit more specific.

I only want the scrollbar to be to the right of the list; the scrollbar should never be to the right of the input form.

Also, the page needs to be able to be resized and have the list expand or shrink to take up the page.

If you look at the [groupme web application](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DW7Xypiogig/maxresdefault.jpg), that's almost exactly what I want.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z1yo22fv/ See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: ** Try adding this CSS to the div you want to overflow...  height: calc(100vh - 40px);  - this takes 100% of the view height, and subtracts 40px to account for the footer height. Will need media query as well for when layout changes:  [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z1yo22fv/) Shows the details

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Official London Talk Page</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    form {
      background: #000;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    form input {
      border: 0;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 90%;
      margin-right: .5%;
    }
    form button {
      width: 9%;
      background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    content {
      width: 100%;
      bottom: 10%;
      display: block;
    }
    #messages {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #messages li {
      padding: 5px 10px;
    }
    #messages li:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #eee;
    }
    .OverflowDiv
    {
      overflow: auto;
      height: calc(100vh - 40px);
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 800px)
    {
        .OverflowDiv
        {
          height: calc(100vh - 75px);
        }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div id="content" class="OverflowDiv">
    <ul id="messages" style="font: 13px Helvetica, Arial;">
      <li>test2</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
      <li>13</li>
      <li>14</li>
      <li>15</li>
      <li>16</li>
      <li>17</li>
      <li>18</li>
      <li>19</li>
      <li>20</li>
      <li>21</li>
      <li>22</li>
      <li>23</li>
      <li>24</li>
      <li>25</li>
      <li>26</li>
      <li>27</li>
      <li>28</li>
      <li>29</li>
      <li>30</li>
      <li>31</li>
      <li>32</li>
      <li>33</li>
      <li>34</li>
      <li>35</li>
      <li>36</li>
      <li>37</li>
      <li>38</li>
      <li>39</li>
      <li>40</li>
      <li>41</li>
      <li>42</li>
      <li>43</li>
      <li>44</li>
      <li>45</li>
      <li>46</li>
      <li>47</li>
      <li>48</li>
      <li>49</li>
      <li>50</li>
      <li>last thing</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="footer" style="position:fixed; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px; overflow:hidden;">
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works as a workaround, thank you. But, I would like it to not have the scrollbar be to the right of the input form. I essentially want to keep the entire list (and scrollbar) **above** the input form on the bottom. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ok, i understand now.  Try adding this to the div with overflow: auto.... height: calc(100vh - 30px); -See edited answer.  May need to add media query for smaller screens where the submit button goes below textbox, and have css be ... height: calc(100vh - 60px)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the height property to the #message until you reach the desired value:

```
<head>
  <title>Official London Talk Page</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    form {
      background: #000;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    form input {
      border: 0;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 90%;
      margin-right: .5%;
    }
    form button {
      width: 9%;
      background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    #content {
      width: 100%;
      bottom: 10%;
      display: block;
    }
    #messages {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      padding: 0;
      height: 300px;
    }
    #messages li {
      padding: 5px 10px;
    }
    #messages li:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #eee;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="overflow:hidden;">
  <div id="content" ; style="overflow:auto;">
    <ul id="messages" style="font: 13px Helvetica, Arial;">
      <li>test2</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
      <li>13</li>
      <li>14</li>
      <li>15</li>
      <li>16</li>
      <li>17</li>
      <li>18</li>
      <li>19</li>
      <li>20</li>
      <li>21</li>
      <li>22</li>
      <li>23</li>
      <li>24</li>
      <li>25</li>
      <li>26</li>
      <li>27</li>
      <li>28</li>
      <li>29</li>
      <li>30</li>
      <li>31</li>
      <li>32</li>
      <li>33</li>
      <li>34</li>
      <li>35</li>
      <li>36</li>
      <li>37</li>
      <li>38</li>
      <li>39</li>
      <li>40</li>
      <li>41</li>
      <li>42</li>
      <li>43</li>
      <li>44</li>
      <li>45</li>
      <li>46</li>
      <li>47</li>
      <li>48</li>
      <li>49</li>
      <li>50</li>
      <li>last thing</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="footer" style="position:fixed; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px; overflow:hidden;">
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me because I still want the messages to expand to fill the page when someone resizes it. I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Also, a margin of 15 pixels seemed to work best for me.